# Align image at the right corner of UIButton irrespective of text length

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Need to align the image on the right corner of UIButton, irrespective of text length. I have managed to set an image on the right of the text but it is placing an image, where the text ends. Below is the code and output that I am getting.

[image]

```
btnSelect.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
btnSelect.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `override` method of `UIButton` and manage your title and image frame.

Here is `UIButton` subclass.

```
class ButtonIconRight: UIButton {
    override func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect:CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var imageFrame = super.imageRect(forContentRect: contentRect)
        imageFrame.origin.x = self.bounds.width - imageFrame.width
        return imageFrame
    }
    
    override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect:CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var titleFrame = super.titleRect(forContentRect: contentRect)
        if (self.currentImage != nil) {
            titleFrame.origin.x = 0
        }
        return titleFrame
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: how to use this

Comment: Opps.. It's basic. Just give this class to the UIButton controller. Still not get ? search how to use the UIButton subclass.